# how to use bootstrap tooltip in asp.net web form pages?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

my control code :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="CheckBox_change_data_auction" runat="server" rel="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="اگر مایل به تغییر زمان اتمام حراج کالای خود هستید این گزینه را انتخاب کنید" />
```

I add all bootstrap scripts on head tag and work well.but I can not use tooltip.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="CheckBox_change_data_auction" runat="server" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="اگر مایل به تغییر زمان اتمام حراج کالای خود هستید این گزینه را انتخاب کنید" />
```

I use like up but dont work.I add in master page head this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip(); 
    $('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip();
</script>
```

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place your jQuery code inside a DOMReady handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() {
        $('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip(); 
        $('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip(); 
    });
</script>
```

Alternatively, keep your `script` as it is, but place it right before the `</body>` instead of in the `<head>`

Comment: Have you included jquery.js in your page?

Comment: yes my head codes is:                                                                          <script src="../js/bootstrap-rtl.min.js"></script>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../css/bootstrap-rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: You need to put the script referencing jquery.js *before* bootstap.js

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip(); 
        $('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip(); 
    });
</script>
```

So that it will get executed when `DOM` is ready